# How do calculator parse expressions

Tags: calculator

How do digital calculators convert the expression for parsing? Is it infix, prefix, or postfix? How do calculators solve expressions?

Comment: Erm, **it depends on the calculator**. You can get any kind that you want. What are you actually asking here?

Comment: Question edited. I am confused how calculators convert the expression for parsing. I have searched through Google but it didn't give me the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays it is most common to enter single line expressions in digital calculators just as you would write them down, so normally infix notation. Converting to postfix is a common way to evaluate those expressions in order to solve them.
There are lots of examples around, [this C++ implementation](http://www.lawrence.edu/fast/greggj/CMSC270/Infix.html) has lots of implementation information and also briefly explains handling parentheses, left associative vs. right associative operators and stuff like that.